# Efficient Rice decoding implementation

Tags: c, implementation, compression

I made a naïve implementation of a [Rice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding) decoder (and encoder):

```
void rice_decode(int k) {
    int i = 0
    int j = 0;
    int x = 0;
    while(i < size-k) {
        int q = 0;
        while(get(i) == 0) {
            q++;
            i++;
        }
        x = q<<k;
        i++;
        for(j=0; j<k; j++) {
            x += get(i+j)<<j;
        }
        i += k;
        printf("%i\n", x);
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

with `size` the size of the input bitset, `get(i)` a primitive returning the `i`-th bit of the bitset, and `k` the Rice parameter. As I am concerned with performances, I also made a more elaborate implementation with precomputation, which is faster. However, when I turn the `-O3` flag on in `gcc`, the naïve implementation actually outperforms the latter.

**My question is:** do know any existing efficient implementation of a Rice encoder/decoder (I am more concerned with decoding) that fares better than this (the ones I could find are either slower or comparable) ? Alternatively, do you have any clever idea that could make decoding faster other than precomputation ?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't measuring the performance of `printf`?

Comment: @JacobParker good point, but I actually added the printf here for clarity. I measured the performances without it.

Comment: What's wrong with a look-up-table (precomputation)?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Nothing wrong! Actually, as I mentioned, it turns out to be faster than the naïve solution, except that the optimized naïve solution gives better results than the optimized precomputed version. Perhaps that is what gcc does, only better. I was just curious to see if there was any existing efficient implementation out there.

Comment: A couple of different highly optimized rice decoder implementations in C++ can be found in this guthub project. It is a GPU impl of rice decoding, but also contains C++ classes to both encode and decode different kinds of rice streams with outlier support: https://github.com/mdejong/MetalRice

Answer (score 0):

Rice coding can be viewed as a variant of [variable-length codes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code) Consequently, in the past I've used table-based techniques to generate automata/state machines that decode fixed huffman codes and rice codes quickly. A quick search about the web for [fast variable-length codes](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20variable-length%20codes) or [fast huffman](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20huffman) yield many applicable results, some of them table-based.

Answer (score 0):

There are some textbook bithacks applicable here.

`while (get(i) == 0) { q++; i++;}` finds the least significant bit set in a stream.

That can be replaced with `-data & data`, which returns a single bit set. That can be converted to index 'q' with some hash + LUT (e.g the one involving modulus with 37. -- or using SSE4 instructions with crc32, I'd bet one can simply do `LUT[crc32(-data&data) & 63]`;

The next loop `for(j=0; j<k; j++) x += get(i+j)<<j;` OTOH should be replaced with `x+= data & ((1<<k)-1);` as one simply gets k bits from a stream and treats them as an unsigned integer.

Finally one shifts `data>>=(q+k);` and reads in enough bytes from input stream.

Comment: Actually, since the `data` is a table containing millions to billion bits, I am not sure you can do things like that, but maybe I'm wrong. Also, isn't this the kind of stuff (maybe not all of it) `gcc -O3` does already ?

Comment: `data` should be a buffer of 32-64 bits, associated with variable `datalen` containing the number of bits feed from the bigger buffer. Once datalen < threshold (say 16); one fills it by 8, 16 or 32 bits. That's fast. No compiler will do it for you automatically. I don't think that even the state of the art compilers are smart enough to see the purpose of get(i) associated with the counters, bend some rules and derive a better algorithm.